# How do I draw a segment of a circle in Lua in Corona?

Tags: lua, drawing, coronasdk

long time ago is last time I needed that :)

I simple like to create a circle with a segment and a different filling or transparent.
So i just have like a stopwatch filling up the circle by time (60 seconds).

function kind a > showsegment (xcircle,ycircle,radius, seconds) :}@

any short lines leading to that solution, are welcome.
The code needs to work within the Corona Framework, in Lua.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. Using image with alpha and tint is not an option?
Yes, you'll have to create 60 objects, one for every tick, but images are cached anyway, so you only loading it and allocating memory for it once. Every next instance is cheap.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you're looking for, but seeing the question it made me curious, so I messed around with it and figured this (if it's what you're looking for):
    tick = 0;
    ticks = {};

```
cr = 250; -- Circle radius
hr = 0.9; -- hand radius
hw = 10; -- hand width
mr = 0.25; -- middle radius (fg)

bg = display.newCircle(cr, cr, cr); -- background
for i=1,360 do
    local w = hr * (cr * 2);
    local x = (w/2)+(((cr*2) - w)/2);
    local t = display.newRect(x,x,hw,w);
    t:rotate(i-1);
    t:setFillColor(0,0, 0);

    table.insert(ticks, t);
end


function drawTick(e)
    print("tick "..tick);
    local dg = display.newGroup();
    local w = hr * (cr * 2);
    local x = (w/2)+(((cr*2) - w)/2);
    local t = display.newRect(dg, 0, -w/4, 10, w/2);

    dg.x = x;
    dg.y = x;
    t:setFillColor(0, 1, 0);
    dg:rotate(tick-1);

    table.insert(ticks, t);
    fg = display.newCircle(cr,cr,mr*cr);

    if tick < 361 then
        tick = tick + 1
        timer.performWithDelay(50, drawTick);
    end
end

timer.performWithDelay(0, drawTick);
```

EDIT: I cleaned up the code a bit.